# Full Screen HTML video background ratio issue

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video, fullscreen

I have been wracking my brain with this and cant figure it out.  I am trying to do a full screen html5 video contained in a div similar to what is seen on http://designmodo.com/startup/

I have a container div "vscenter".
In the css I have it set to

```
#vscenter {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
```

I have a jquery that detect the height of the browser window and includes that height into the container div.

```
$(function(){
    $('#vscenter').css({'height':(($(window).height())-0)+'px'});



$(window).resize(function(){    
$('#vscenter').css({'height':(($(window).height())-0)+'px'});
});
```

});

For the video I have it set up like this in CSS:

```
#video_background { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%; 
    width: auto; 
    height: auto; 
    z-index: -1000; 
    //overflow: hidden;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

You can see the effect here in its current form:  www.dyhas.com/jonas

The issue is the video is not in fact strecthing to 100% height.  I can only surmise this is because the aspect ratio of the video is affecting this?   Is there a way to override this?

Strangley,
If I change the top and left attributes on #video_background to bottom right, the video will move to the top of the page and bar appears on the bottom.  However, as the monitor shrinks, the video gets pushed up off the page (cutting off the heads of the people on the video):

Am I going all wrong here?  Is there an easier way to achieve this?  I have tried various javascripts but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  Turns out I just needed to convert the video to mp4 and webm once again using the proper size.